# I want to post some posts using python on Wordpress website

Tags: python, wordpress, python-2.7, .htaccess

I'm Having a bit of a problem while using  `python-wordpress-xmlrpc`  library in my python script to post to my own wordpress 3.5 site. My script is fine, I know this because I used to use the same script to post on other wordpress sites that I had access to a while back. However, now when I try to post on my wordpress site, I get an error. The following is the link that I  used to write my script:

https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

here is the code that i'm using to post to my wordpress site..I'm using python interpretor 2.7..

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo

wp = Client('http://mysite.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')

    post = WordPressPost()
    post.title = 'My new title'
    post.content = 'This is the body of my new post.'
    post.terms_names = {
    'post_tag': ['test', 'firstpost'],
    'category': ['Introductions', 'Tests']
    }

wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

The error is thrown on this line:

```
 wp = Client('http://mysite.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/moiz.ahmad/Desktop/python/project13 MarketingLand + Entrepreneurb c/sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    wp = Client('http://bull.pk/xmlrpc.php', 'moiz', 'password12345')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wordpress_xmlrpc\base.py", line 24, in _init_
    self.supported_methods = self.server.mt.supportedMethods()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in _call_
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1316, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1487, in parse_response
    p.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 558, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 222
```

Is there any kind of modification that I have to do on my wordpress site?

Comment: Do you feel like telling us what the error actually is, or are we supposed to guess?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not a code solution but what about using a service like https://ifttt.com/. I used it for a project like yours. It was a python script on a Raspberry Pi, that was able to post on a blog on wordpress.com. 
To achieve this, I posted on Twitter instead of Wordpress with this easy library http://www.tweepy.org/ and the connected Twitter posts with Wordpress posts via IFTTT.
I know it sounds crazy but it saved me a lot of time with that library that you are using for Wordpress.

Comment: but I don't want to use twitter i just want to use python directly to do this task